# Space after left-aligned image and its text on the right

Tags: wordpress

I'm a newbie Wordpress user and I'm trying to do that;

An image which is left-aligned and a text about that image on the right side of the image.

That's ok, but when I try to enter the next first line after the image, it makes me to push "enter" multiple times until the height of the image ends.

But in real it's a multiple spaces after the text and it differs from monitor to monitor with their resolutions...

For example on mobile there is so many space after the text because I pushed enter multiple times to enter the next line after the left-aligned image...

I'm getting crazy, please help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using multiple `<p>` elements just add a css rule.

```
<p>
    <img src="asd-md.png"  align="left">
    hola
</p>

<p style="clear:both" >
    hola 2
 </p>
```

If you have everything inside a paragraph element you could use this:

```
<p>
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/j/X/R/c/7/asd-md.png"  align="left">
    hola
    <br clear="all" >
    hola 2
 </p>
```